# React context consumer how to access ref on to the consuming component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've build a higher order component using the [new context API of React](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) and I am trying to to find a way to be able to access the reference (via `ref()`) of a wrapped child component.

**tl/dr:** Essentially I want to [forward the ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) from the `Consumer` to the actual component.

Here's a specific example. The `RootComponent` sets the value for the `CoolProvider` that is suppose to be exposed on all *wrapped* child components. A child component is wrapped using `withCool()` such that it can access `props.cool`. (Of course in a real world example everything is much more complex and there are dozens of components.)

Now independent of knowing whether a child component has been wrapped I would like to be able to get a reference to it via `ref()` as illustrated in `RootComponent` but unfortunately the wrapped components do not support `ref()` anymore as they are functional!

Check out this live demo (https://jsfiddle.net/64t0oenz/3/) and inspect the web console. You will see that only the callback for the non-wrapped component fires.

My question is: is there a way to forward the reference request from the `CoolConsumer` to the actual component such that the parent component can access it's reference?

```
const { Provider: CoolProvider, Consumer: CoolConsumer } = React.createContext();

const withCool = Component => props => (
  <CoolConsumer>
    {cool => <Component {...props} cool={cool} />}
  </CoolConsumer>
);

class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return this.props.cool ? (
        <div>Isn't this cool?</div>
    ) : (
      <div>Not so cool!</div>
    );
  }
}

const CoolChildComponent = withCool(ChildComponent);

class RootComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <CoolProvider value={true}>
        <ChildComponent ref={(c) => { console.log('Normal child ref', c); }}/>
        <CoolChildComponent ref={(c) => { console.log('Cool child ref', c); }}/>
      </CoolProvider>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<RootComponent />, document.querySelector('#cool'));
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured it out! Using React's [`forwardRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) API it is possible to achieve exactly what I was looking for. The only change required is to replace

```
const withCool = Component => props => (
  <CoolConsumer>
    {cool => <Component {...props} cool={cool} />}
  </CoolConsumer>
);
```

with

```
const withCool = Component => React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <CoolConsumer>
    {cool => <Component {...props} cool={cool} ref={ref} />}
  </CoolConsumer>
));
```

Here's the modified live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/64t0oenz/4/
Open the dev console and you will now see 2 console logs printing the reference to the normal and cool component.

Comment: Yes I will but it's not possible within the first 2 days

Answer (score -1):

`ref` just like the `key`, it's not a prop

```
const { Provider: CoolProvider, Consumer: CoolConsumer } = React.createContext();

const withCool = Component => props => {
  const {myRef, ...rest} = props;
  return (
    <CoolConsumer>
      {cool => <Component ref={myRef} {...rest} cool={cool} />}
    </CoolConsumer>
  )
};

class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return this.props.cool ? (
      <div>Isn't this cool?</div>
    ) : (
      <div>Not so cool!</div>
    );
  }
}

const CoolChildComponent = withCool(ChildComponent);

class RootComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <CoolProvider value={true}>
        <ChildComponent ref={(c) => { console.log('Normal child ref', c); }}/>
        <CoolChildComponent myRef={(c) => { console.log('Cool child ref', c); }}/>
      </CoolProvider>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<RootComponent />, document.querySelector('#cool'));
```

Comment: Yeah I know that but it doesn't answer my question. Also, what is the `key` you mention?

Comment: @FLekschas Did you run my code? It works fine. `key` is what you add to elements inside an array. see [forwarding-refs-in-higher-order-components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-in-higher-order-components)

Comment: It might work but that's not what I asked for. In your case the parent needs to know whether the child is wrapped or not. The parent can't just use `ref` as usual. Instead it has to use `myRef` or am I missing something?