# In React, is it possible to store a ref in a context?

Tags: html, reactjs

I need global app-wide access to a VideoElement to play it on user events on browsers like Safari and was wondering if storing the VideoElement in a context would be the best way to do that. I programmatically play my video through a redux action and in Safari that is not possible unless it has been played once through a user triggered event (like a click)

Is it possible to store an element (ref) within a context? The VideoElement will be then rendered within the component which I want to have my video, and then other components will also have access to the context and be able to call functions such as `usePlayVideo` that based on the context's state, will either call videoElement.play() if this is the first time the video is being played, or dispatch the redux action to play the video programmatically otherwise

Comment: if it just a handler, I think you dont even need a live props. all you need is a global variable to set and get

Answer (score 12):

It is possible to store a ref into context! You need to create a context at first. Then you need to pass value to the context provider and create a ref object using useRef hook. After that, you pass the ref into the value.

Now, You have a ref object sharing between components under the context provider and if you want to retrieve or pass a new ref, you could use useContext hook to deal with it.

Here is the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-flower-fkuon?file=/src/App.js:0-948) (codesandbox).

Here is the sample code.

```
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const MyContext = createContext();

export const ContextStore = (props) => {
  const ref = useRef();
  return <MyContext.Provider value={ref}>{props.children}</MyContext.Provider>;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <ContextStore>
        <MyComponent />
        <MyComponent2 />
      </ContextStore>
    </>
  );
}

const MyComponent = () => {
  const myContext = useContext(MyContext);

  return (
    <div className="App" ref={myContext}>
      <h1>Hello MyComponent1</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

const MyComponent2 = () => {
  const myContext = useContext(MyContext);
  const [divRef, setDivRef] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    setDivRef(myContext);
  }, [myContext]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{divRef?.current && divRef.current.innerText}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: This is a wrong approach, the ref will be recreated everytime `ContextStore` is used so this wont preserve ref's current value. You should define the ref (using `React.createRef()`) outside context provider (outside `ContextStore`)

Comment: In React Docs, it says "useRef returns a mutable ref object whose .current property is initialized to the passed argument (initialValue). The returned object will persist for the full lifetime of the component."  If you recreate the  ContextStore, it will lose the ref definitely, but there is no recreate in the example.  
the question is storing ref in context.  ContextStore will keep your ref data no matter how it "rerender".

Comment: Yes this will work only if you put the provider on the root of your app (to be able to use the context anywhere needed) and should be used **only once**, but you wont be able to only wrap the component that needs the provider, becuase with this approach, every time the provider is used, it will create a new Ref object and the component wrapped inside provider, will receive a new empty ref object. [Here's the scenario that fails with this approach](https://codesandbox.io/s/pass-ref-to-context-forked-5rx3og?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Not sure what exactly is failing in your example @ErfanAzary? Using `useRef` in a context is perfectly fine

Comment: @SimonTran of course it's totally fine to use `useRef` inside a context. The only thing, as I've explained above, is that with this approach, the ref will be recreated every time `ContextStore` is used and the ref's current value will not be preserved. which means for example if you put it in two parts of your app tree, children of each `ContextStore` will receive their own fresh empty ref object and cannot access the DOM element.
As you can see in the example, `MyComponent2` should repeat the content of `MyComponent` but it cant because `ref.current` is empty

Answer (score 10):

You can use this approach:

`VideoContext.js`

```
import { createContext, createRef, useContext } from "react";

const VideoContext = createContext();
const videoRef = createRef();

export const VideoContextProvider = (props) => {
  return (
    <VideoContext.Provider value={videoRef}>
      {props.children}
    </VideoContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useVideoContext = () => useContext(VideoContext);
```

and `App.js` for example:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useVideoContext, VideoContextProvider } from "./VideoContext";

const SomeComponent = () => {
  const videoRef = useVideoContext();

  return (
    <div ref={videoRef}>
      <h1>Hey</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

const SomeOtherComponent = () => {
  const [ref, setRef] = useState();
  const videoRef = useVideoContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    setRef(videoRef);
  }, [videoRef]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{ref?.current?.innerText}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <VideoContextProvider>
        <SomeComponent />
      </VideoContextProvider>

      {/* ... */}

      {/* Some other component in another part of the tree */}
      <VideoContextProvider>
        <SomeOtherComponent />
      </VideoContextProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```

[code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-ref-as-context-79ut38?file=/src/App.js:0-838)

Comment: this is better than the one that get most voted as creating  `ref` outside the `provider` will prevent the `context provider` from being recreated every time `VideoContextProvider` is used so it will preserve ref's current value.

Comment: This doesn't work. You can not use `useRef` outside of a functional component

Answer (score 2):

I used this approach:

first I creacted the context and ContextProvider;

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

export const ScrollContext = React.createContext();

const ScrollContextProvider = (props) => {
  return (
    <ScrollContext.Provider
      value={{
        productsRef: useRef(),
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </ScrollContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ScrollContextProvider;
```

then Added my provider in my index.js:

```
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ScrollContextProvider>
      <App />
    </ScrollContextProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

after that I used my context where I needed it:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { ScrollContext } from "../../store/scroll-context";

const Products = () => {
  const scrollCtx = useContext(ScrollContext);

  return (
    <section ref={scrollCtx.productsRef}>
      // your code...
    </section>
  );
};
```

In my case I wanted to to scroll to the above component clicking a button from a different component:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { ScrollContext } from "../../store/scroll-context";


function Header() {
  const scrollCtx = useContext(ScrollContext);

  const scrollTo = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      scrollCtx.productsRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    }, 0);
  };

  return (
    <header>
      //your code ...
      <button alt="A table with chair" onClick={scrollTo}>Order Now<button />
    </header>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not? I'll say. Let's see if we can setup an example.

```
const fns = {}
const addDispatch = (name, fn) => { fns[name] = fn }
const dispatch = (name) => { fns[name] && fns[name]() }
const RefContext = createContext({ addDispatch, dispatch })
export default RefContext
```

```
const Child1 = () => {
  const [video, dispatchVideo] = useState(...)
  const { addDispatch } = useContext(RefContext)
  useEffect(() => {
    addDispatch('video', dispatchVideo)
  }, [])
}

const Child2 = () => {
  const { dispatch } = useContext(RefContext)
  const onClick = () => { dispatch('video') }
  ...
}
```

The above two childs do not have to share the same ancestor.

I didn't use ref the way you wanted, but i think you can pass your ref to one of  the function. This is a very basic idea. I haven't tested it yet. But seems it could work. A bit

Answer (score -5):

No. It's not possible to use Ref on context api. React ref is considered to be used on rendering element.

What you're looking for is to [forward the ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html), so that you can [consume them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53200952/2138752) wherever you want.

Comment: Factually not correct, perhaps a matter of opinion